# JSON parsing with Jackson - values skipped

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I am trying to parse a feed given from a request to Facebook. However, my parser is skipping a lot of information. Below is a part of the code, an example of what is being parsed and what the prints in the if statements are printing. For example, no "message" is ever found. Ideas?

```
List<FacebookItem> list = new ArrayList<FacebookItem>();

try {
    if (jFactory == null)
        jFactory = new JsonFactory();

    jParser = jFactory.createJsonParser(json);

    FacebookItem o = null;
    while (jParser.nextToken() != null) {
        if ("type".equals(jParser.getCurrentName())) {
            jParser.nextToken();
            o = new FacebookItem();
            o.setType(jParser.getText());
            System.out.println("Found type:   " + jParser.getText());
        }
        if ("from".equals(jParser.getCurrentName()))
            while (!"name".equals(jParser.getCurrentName())) {
                jParser.nextToken();
            }
            jParser.nextToken();
            o.getUser().setUserName(jParser.getText());
            System.out.println("Found name:   " + jParser.getText());
        }
        if ("message".equals(jParser.getCurrentName())) {
            jParser.nextToken();
            o.setText(jParser.getText());
            System.out.println("Found message:   " + jParser.getText());
        }
        if ("created_time".equals(jParser.getCurrentName())) {
            jParser.nextToken();
            o.setTimestamp(jParser.getText());
            System.out.println("Found created_time:   " + jParser.getText());
            list.add(o);
        }
    }
    jParser.close();

} catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JsonMappingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

> {"data":[{"type":"photo","link":"http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151331660204305&set=a.299455459304.180838.197394889304&type=1&relevant_count=1","from":{"name":"FC Barcelona","category":"Professional sports
>   team","id":"197394889304"},"message":"Puyol faces eight week layoff
>   http://bit.ly/QXhOFE\r\n\r\nPuyol, vuit setmanes de baixa
>   http://bit.ly/T1enma\r\n\r\nPuyol, ocho semanas de baja
>   http://bit.ly/T0eaj8","picture":"http://photos-g.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/246623_10151331660204305_75156416_s.jpg","created_time":"2012-10-03T17:40:06+0000","id":"197394889304_10151331937599305"},{"type":"checkin","link":"http://www.facebook.com/pages/Hubben-21/249474758405147","from":{"name":"Andreas
>   Rol\u00e9n","id":"575703056"},"message":"En timme in i turneringen och
>   redan
>   chipleader","picture":"http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/static-ak/rsrc.php/v2/y5/r/j258ei8TIHu.png","name":"Hubben
>   2.1","created_time":"2012-10-03T17:24:19+0000","id":"575703056_10151181582028057"},{"type":"photo","link":"http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151445544542786&set=at.10151445533587786.588547.694032785.688088336&type=1&relevant_count=1","from":{"name":"Jens Wilhelmsson","id":"688088336"},"picture":"http://photos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/72091_10151445544542786_676020840_s.jpg","created_time":"2012-10-03T17:21:40+0000","id":"688088336_10151111148358337"},{"type":"link","from":{"name":"Eric
>   Lindqvist","id":"648057222"},"created_time":"2012-10-03T17:20:52+0000","id":"648057222_10151249963167223"}

```
Found type:   photo
Found name:   FC Barcelona
Found name:   Andreas Rolén
Found name:   Hubben 2.1
Found created_time:   2012-10-03T17:24:19+0000
Found type:   photo
Found name:   Jens Wilhelmsson
Found name:   Eric Lindqvist
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but I suggest you use GSON.

Comment: Would you please explain why?

Comment: Syntax is a lot cleared and it works without any problem.. at least as far as I tested it.

Comment: I liked GSON too but found that Jackson was considerably faster in my use case and just as easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like Jackson, it's fast and very capable.  I've never used the streaming API (which you are using here), but it sure looks like the hard way.  unless you are very concerned about memory usage, I would suggest you don't use the streaming API.  Since you are on mobile, there is obviously more concern about resources, so that's your call.

If you decide to forego the streaming API it's easiest to create a java object model that maps to your JSON, then use the ObjectMapper to read the string into that object model.  You can customize the conversion using annotations to rename fields for your mapping or whatever.  Something like the following should work (depending on what FacebookItem really is defined as.)

```
  import org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig.Feature;
  ....
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  // tell it to not fail on properties that you don't have mapped, that way you
  // only have to map the fields you are interested in and can ignore the rest
  mapper.getDeserializationConfig().set(Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
  ItemContainer itemContainer = mapper.readValue(facebookDataJsonString, ItemContainer.class);

  // where elsewhere you have defined something like:

  class ItemContainer {
    List<FacebookItem> data;
    // getters and setters for data.
  }
```

Following is the option specified by eugen in the comments.  This will work if your JSON contains a list (i.e. doesn't have the "data" wrapper but instead looks like `[{...},{...}]`:

```
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  // tell it to not fail on properties that you don't have mapped, that way you
  // only have to map the fields you are interested in and can ignore the rest
  mapper.getDeserializationConfig().set(Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
  List<FacebookItem> items = mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<Stuff>>(){});
```

Finally, a third option is to just read it into a Map if you don't have an object mapping.  Then at least you don't have to deal with the JSONObject and JSONArray stuff.

```
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  Map<String, Object> container = mapper.readValue(facebookDataJsonString, Map.class);
  List<Map<String,Object>> = container.get("data");
  for (Map<String,Object> map : container ) {
    System.out.println( "type is " + map.get("type"));
    System.out.println( "from is " + ((Map<String,Object>)map.get("from")).get("name"));
    System.out.println( "message is " + map.get("message"));
  }
```

Comment: Your first example will not work as Jackson will deserialize into a List of maps instead of a List of FacebookItem

Comment: Thanks eugen.  I've fixed it so that it has a container object in order to match the sample JSON given, which should then allow for parsing a List of FacebookItems.

Comment: You are welcome. Like Genson GenericType, jackson provides a class called TypeReference that allows you to work with parameterized types, new TypeReference<List<FacebookItem>>(){}.getType()

Comment: certainly, I was happy to learn about TypeReference from eugen. I hadn't had to play with that before.

Answer (score 1):

I dont really know your JSON library, but Android provides a [nice JSON API in the SDK itself](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html), why not using it?

```
JSONArray data = new JSONArray(jsonString);
int itemCount = data.length();
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>(itemCount);

for (int i=0; i<itemCount; ++i) {
  JSONObject item = data.getJSONObject(i);

  String name = item.getString("name");
  String message = item.optString("message");

  MyObject o = new MyObject(name, message);
  list.add(o);
}
```

Best would even be to encapsulate the JSON parsing for a single item into the MyObject class:

```
JSONArray data = new JSONArray(jsonString);
int itemCount = data.length();
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>(itemCount);

for (int i=0; i<itemCount; ++i) {
  JSONObject item = data.getJSONObject(i);

  MyObject o = new MyObject();
  o.setFromJSON(item);
  list.add(o);
}
```

Comment: That's quite a bit more code than Jackson or GSON with data-binding. And it can not do streaming (incremental) parsing, so memory usage can be substantially higher as well.

Comment: org.json is very very slow. It's not a good idea to suggest to use it

Answer (score -1):

First of all - JSON string is incomplete - it missing ]} at the end. When I attached it, my costom built JSON parser gets these results:

```
  data:
    id=197394889304_10151331937599305
    picture=http://photos-g.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/246623_10151331660204305_75156416_s.jpg
    message=Puyol faces eight week layoff http://bit.ly/QXhOFE\r\n\r\nPuyol, vuit setmanes de baixa http://bit.ly/T1enma\r\n\r\nPuyol, ocho semanas de baja http://bit.ly/T0eaj8
    link=http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151331660204305&set=a.299455459304.180838.197394889304&type=1&relevant_count=1
    from:
      id=197394889304
      category=Professional sports team
      name=FC Barcelona
    created_time=2012-10-03T17:40:06+0000
    type=photo
    id=575703056_10151181582028057
    picture=http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/static-ak/rsrc.php/v2/y5/r/j258ei8TIHu.png
    message=En timme in i turneringen och redan chipleader
    name=Hubben 2.1
    link=http://www.facebook.com/pages/Hubben-21/249474758405147
    from:
      id=575703056
      name=Andreas Rol\u00e9n
    created_time=2012-10-03T17:24:19+0000
    type=checkin
    id=688088336_10151111148358337
    picture=http://photos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/72091_10151445544542786_676020840_s.jpg
    link=http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151445544542786&set=at.10151445533587786.588547.694032785.688088336&type=1&relevant_count=1
    from:
      id=688088336
      name=Jens Wilhelmsson
    created_time=2012-10-03T17:21:40+0000
    type=photo
    id=648057222_10151249963167223
    from:
      id=648057222
      name=Eric Lindqvist
    created_time=2012-10-03T17:20:52+0000
    type=link
```

My question now - is everything OK here? Any errors?